# Can I launch a Chrome App from an extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My understanding is that unlike a chrome extension, a chrome app cannot run a background script that interacts with various Chrome pages.

I need the chrome app because extensions do not provide access to the microphone.  However, I need the extension to assist users in the browsing experience.

Is there any way for the extension to launch the application and pass data to it?

Answer (score 2):

Chrome apps do indeed not have a [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages), but [event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/event_pages) are still supported. You can simply use [cross-extension messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external) to communicate between your extension and app in order to launch the app.

And note that extensions *can* use the microphone, you just need to ask the user for its permission. Since `chrome-extension:`-URLs are viewed as secure schemes, the permission will be remembered, so if the user approves the media stream permissions once, your extension will have access to the microphone until the user visits `chrome://settings/contentExceptions#media-stream` and clears the permissions. You can request this permission from a new tab/window, or from an iframe that embeds your extension page that calls `getUserMedia`.

(a request to enable the audioCapture and videoCapture permissions in extensions has been posted at [crbug.com/160337](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=160337); you might be interested in starring the issue to get notified of progress updates.)

Answer (score -1):

i think what you are looking for is

```
chrome --app-id={your app id here}
```

Comment: No, that is not it. An extension cannot call the command line.